# MS Access backend for django

Tags: django, ms-access, django-pyodbc

I've been working on a modification of the django-pyodbc package so that it could be used with MS Access.

I need this for a legacy database we are tied to at my organization, and have been doing a rather hacky job specific to my situation, but have also been making useful, generalizable progress in terms of adapting SQL syntax for MS Access.

My question is, is this a project that anyone else in the world is interested in? should I clean up my code and try to fully generalize it, or is everyone else in the world able to solve their MS Access problems by moving to SQL server?

Comment: Perhaps setting up your Access (i.e., Jet/ACE) database as a linked server in SQL Server would help you avoid localizing for Jet/ACE?

Comment: Yes, I think you will find people interested in this project.  I have a specific instance in which I could use it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I would move the data to SQL Server if that is an option.

If moving the data is not an option and if my Django app is already connecting to SQL Server, I might just [create a linked server on SQL Server](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Microsoft-Access/Configuring-a-Linked-Microsoft-Access-Server-on-SQL-2005-Server/) and go through SQL Server instead.

Comment: I mostly finished the implementation (introspection + admin system = working, test suite = unfinished), but I have two issues, limitations of the JET ODBC engine:

1. 127 column limit in a SELECT query in Jet 
2. Performance = awful.

From the link above:
"Usage of such data are only limited by the limitations of the Access database. In MS SQL 2005 server the external data is accessed through the OLEDB interface, and the limitations are those imposed by this provider."

Does anyone have info that might shed light on whether linking servers would provide a workaround for speed or column limit?

Comment: not sure why this got voted down. it seems like a practical solution, although not the solution they user was looking for.